Unity virtual mouse working for UI, but not firing OnMouseEnter/OnMouseDown events for 2D colliders
I'm setting up controller support for my game using a virtual mouse and the new Unity input system.
The virtual mouse works for interacting with UI; however, I've found that for 2D elements, it won't fire the OnMouseEnter and/or OnMouseDown events:

If the cursor mode is set to "Hardware Cursor", OnMouseEnter will fire, but NOT OnMouseDown
If the cursor mode is set to "Software Cursor", neither event will fire.

Note about setup:

In my project settings, "Active Input Handling" is set to Both.
These events DO fire correctly when using a normal mouse. It's only the virtual mouse that isn't interacting correctly.
My camera has a Physics2DRaycaster attached, and the EventMask is set to hit the Default layer, which is the layer my testing object is on.

The 2D object I'm using for testing is super simple: Kinematic 2D rigid body, 2D collider, and the following basic script:

private void OnMouseEnter()
{
    Debug.Log("OnMouseEnter");
}

private void OnMouseDown()
{
    Debug.Log("OnMouseDown");
}


Anyone have any suggestions for what to try?
I tried changing the cursor mode to Hardware Cursor, but it still doesn't fire OnMouseDownEvents.
I tried adding a Physics2DRaycaster to my camera, and that didn't change anything.

This question is similar to: Unity C# OnMouseDown() does not work.. Why?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You dont mention the requirements here https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html have been covered.. Please check

Have you considered IPointerEnterHandler instead? I'm quite sure that these two OnMouseXY events are indeed limited to the actual mouse

No, PointerEnter/PointerDown events don't function either. It seems that Unity's virtual mouse is unable to interact with anything besides UI.  I've gone with using Physics2D.OverlapPoint() on an update loop instead, which is working for me.

From what I can tell, the VirtualMouse component was only ever designed to work with UI, and does not properly emulate a hardware mouse. Unfortunately, Unity doesn't properly document what exactly counts as "clicked".
A possible albeit crude solution would be to warp the system's actual mouse cursor to the position of the virtual one using the Mouse.WarpCursorPosition() method.
There may also be a configuration issue. I was looking through the Unity forms and found a similar issue, here, and it seems that the virtual mouse doesn't get assigned the same way as a hardware one resulting in some actions not triggering.
This solution, found by the user "RaspberryPuppies" seems to have worked for a couple people over there.
I don't have access to a gamepad to test with so I am unfortunately unable to verify that these solutions will work in your case. Either way, best of luck to you.

Unfortunately, following the advice posted by RaspberryPuppies did not fix the issue in my case. I've gone with using Physics2D.OverlapPoint() on an update loop instead, which is working for me. Thanks for responding!
